# Enabling ? in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems with my URL. My urls are modrewrited and until now I didn't know that I can access stuff in url only when there is & ( question-mark with $_GET don't work ).

> So for example www.example.com/?go=1 $_GET['go'] not 1 But if I make
>   it like this www.example.com/&go=1 then it works.

I want question-mark to work. What am I missing?

here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I always forget this option. I still prefer adding %{QUERY_STRING} though... don't know why. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change last rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are rewriting everything

```
^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1
```

so your successful request to &go=1 gets rewritten as /index.php?s=&go=1 and that is a valid request.

Your bad request to ?go=1 gets rewritten as /index.php?s=?go=1 and that is not valid